# Generate number every 3 seconds and update current number

Tags: java, oop, java-8

I'm trying to generate a number every 3 seconds and update the current number. I'm able to generate number every 3 seconds; However, the current number isn't updated. I apperciate any help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
      
            CurrentNum=task2();
        
            System.out.println("Result    ====    "+CurrentNum);

        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
     System.out.println("CurrentNum    ====    "+CurrentNum);
     
    
}
public static int task2() {
    // create instance of Random class 
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999 
    int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000); 
    
    return rand_int1;
}
```

output:

```
    CurrentNum    ====    0
    Result    ====    631
    Result    ====    789
    Result    ====    958
```

I want the output to be:

```
    Result    ====    631
    CurrentNum ====    631
    Result    ====    789
    CurrentNum====    789
```

Comment: I think you should read more about runnable. The code is not linear. After setting up the executor service you print out  CurrentNum which doesn't have the new random value. i.e
CurrentNum    ====    0
Afterwards the runnable runs assigning new value to CurrentNum.
If you are just looking for that output just move 
     System.out.println("CurrentNum    ====    "+CurrentNum);
into the runnable.

Comment: You should move that Random instance out to class level and make it static so that it gets reused each time and not make a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

The print for CurrentNum will only get printed once because it will only run once. Since the runnable is running on an interval, that will get called every 3 seconds. If you want the print for CurrentNum to be printed, you move the `System.out.println("CurrentNum    ====    "+CurrentNum);` Line Inside the helloRunnable function.

```
System.out.println("CurrentNum    ====    "+CurrentNum);

CurrentNum=task2();
        
System.out.println("Result    ====    "+CurrentNum);
```